# Не получается установить Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, openserver

Сижу на Windows 10, использую Open Server. Первым делом установил Composer и обновил его через консоль при помощи `composer self-update`, он обновился.

Далее через команду `composer global require "laravel/installer"` загрузил установщик

После запускаю команду `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel myFirstApp`, но в процессе консоль закрывается и я так понимаю, что не все папки устанавливаются.

В итоге перехожу по адресу в браузере `first-exp.laravel/myFirstApp/public` и вылетает ошибка вместо страницы приветствия.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уверен, что ошибка глупая, но найти не могу. Почему вылетает консоль на полпути и не отображает сам процесс установки. В созданной папке myFirstApp нет директории Vendors, хотя по-моему она должна находиться там.

Comment: А что за путь такой странный? И судя по ошибке vendor папка пустая или её нет.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в Avast, целый вечер убил. Отключил антивирус и всё установилось нормально. Ещё и в режиме без уведомлений стоял)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была не только именно из за Avast, по большей степени так же могла и возмущаться Windows защита. (Антивирус "боится" непонятных пакетов вот и не дал). Совет - Попробуй пострадать с дистрибутивом Ubuntu. Скачай на какую нибудь виртуальную машину и попробуй по пользоваться тем терминалом. Я в ubuntu вижу больше возможностей чем в винде.